# A hashable, flexible identifier in python

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, immutability

I'm trying to make some sort of hashable identifier in python; I need it to identify nodes in a graph. The trouble is that some nodes have different attributes. If the attributes of these nodes are portrayed by dictionaries of the attributes to values:

```
idA = {'type':'A', 'name':'a_100'}
idB = {'type':'B', 'name':'b_3', 'value':7}
```

I want `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` to use the tuple pairs `((key1,value1), (key2,value2), ...)`.

Dictionaries would be ideal for this, because I'm going to check these properties fairly frequently, and dictionary lookup should be efficient (I'm using many identifiers and each will have many attributes). But dictionaries are not hashable.

A frozenset of the tuple pairs would hash properly, but would it be efficient for lookup?

If I declare an empty class, and then set attributes for it, that does what I want (possibly using a dictionary under the hood), but I don't know how to hash it. Maybe there's some way to hash it's member values using `inspect` or `dir()`?

```
class identifier():
    pass
idA = identifier()
idA.type = 'A'
idA.name = 'a_100'
```

If there is a way to use a hash (and == operator) based on tuple pairs of (attribute, value), then this would also do what I want.

Or is there some work around that can make the equivalent data type that would satisfy this SAT-type analogy: `frozenset` is to `set` as ? is to `dict`

Thanks for your help.

---

Edit:

Is this the right direction?

```
class identifier(dict):
    def to_frozenset(self):
        return frozenset([(k,self[k]) for k in self])
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.to_frozenset())
    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        return self.to_frozenset() == rhs.to_frozenset()
    def __ne__(self, rhs):
        return not self == rhs
```

This shifts the computational complexity so that it is fast to lookup an identifier attribute, but slow to hash an identifier or check two identifiers for equality. If there were a way to cache its hash (and disallow its dictionary to change once the hash was cached), and we were guaranteed few hash collisions of identifier types (so checking for equality were rare), then maybe that would be a good solution? Let me know what you think!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you saying that you have a `Node` class, but that different instances of it have different attributes?

Comment: Exactly. Some nodes are of type 'A', and some are of type 'B'. The type 'B' nodes have some different attributes. I also want to be able to quickly lookup an attribute for a node (like 'type') so I can quickly make a subgraph of just those nodes (for visualizing the graph).

Comment: I'm still confused about what you are __actually trying to do__. Ignoring for the moment all the stuff about `__hash__` and `__eq__` and `frozenset`, what is the specific use case which you are trying to optimise?

Comment: I have a graph of these identifiers. I lookup attribute values for these identifiers frequently. I also will hash the identifiers frequently, because that is how NetworkX (the graph package I am using) indexes nodes. I already know that my graph is quite large (at least 10,000 -- 100,000 nodes), so slow hashing will be detrimental. I also am going to lookup attributes very often, and the number of attributes is not trivial (<10), so using tuples of key-value pairs will slow down lookup substantially.

Comment: Use the built-in `id()` function as the hash of each dictionary, or put them all in a list and use the list index as the hash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inherit from dict, encapsulate it. That way you can make sure it won't be changed.

As for caching, you can remember to_frozenset or its hash. Depending on the use pattern, remember the hash, which allows you to quickly return on hashing and inequality, and compare the frozensets only if the hashes match.

That said, you're much too worried about performance for someone who hasn't coded a benchmark yet. Build the simplest possible implementation. If it's fast you're done. Otherwise, benchmark it, then find an incremental way to improve measured results.

Comment: I'm not too worried about performance-- I coded it as tuples and my program ran for many minutes instead of one minute. Encapsulating a dictionary inside an `identifier` class did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Good! Sorry I assumed too much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `frozendict`. But a [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is an approximation to that behaviour which may suit you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this solves your problem, but if you want an object to be hashable, you can implement it in this fashion:

```
class Hashable(object):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.__class__.__name__,
                     tuple(self.__dict__.items())))
```

You'll get the data of the object in structured tuple format, along with the class name as a hash signature of some king. You can even extend `dict` to use in this class.

Comment: It should be noted that changing the values will change hash which should __never__ happen.